# How can I detect the views whose constraints are being unsatisfied?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am constantly getting this error:

> 2014-09-13 23:56:19.904 Parrot[245:60b] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
>   Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this:
>   (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect;
>   (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it.
>   (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints)

```
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x14641170 H:[UILabel:0x14641060(200)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x14643670 H:[UILabel:0x14641060]-(60)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x14641590 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x146436a0 H:|-(60)-[UILabel:0x14641060]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x14641590 )>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x1464bc70 h=--& v=--& H:[UIView:0x14641590(480)]>"
)
```

How can I detect the views whose constraints are being unsatisfied?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [UILabel:0x14641060]

It's in error message.

It seems this `UILabel` has three constraints. Remove any one of these you can satisfy the constraints

Comment: how can I know to which UILabel is 0x14641060 refering to in my storyboard?

Comment: @user3726682 the one that you constrain its width is 200, leading space and trailing space to screen boundary are 60